# sqlite CLI - can't run large create query

Tags: sqlite

The following command in the sqlite CLI does not work (ellipses are expanded in the actual command):

`create table a ('c0, c1, c2, c3, ..., c1000');`

I'm just left with the `...>` prompt until I quit out with this error message:

`Error: unrecognized token: "'c0, c1, ..., c697,"` (with ellipses expanded).

Incidentally, creating a table with up to 698 columns works.

It doesn't seem like I'm actually hitting SQLite's limits though, so why does this happen? https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

> The default setting for SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN is 2000.
>
> The maximum number of bytes in the text of an SQL statement is limited to SQLITE_MAX_SQL_LENGTH which defaults to 1000000.

(For the purposes of this question, disregard the wisdom of creating a table with so many columns.)

Comment: You have a big string as only content of the `()` in your creation statement. Why?

Comment: Sorry, I've tried without quotes too. And with 'c1', 'c2', ...

Comment: But the error must have been different then...

Comment: Same error. It seems ( ) was only able to accept a string up to a certain length much smaller than what the documentation suggested.

Comment: What, by your understanding, is the meaning of `create table a ('verylongstring');`?

Comment: That was supposed to create a table of 1000 columns delimited by columns in the string (I was thinking Python syntax).

Comment: It is a single string, how do you expect it to create more than one column?

Comment: Obviously I expect it to be interpreted as col1, col2, etc.. in fact this is what works in Python. But I've tried the other quote combinations as previously mentioned for the CLI too.

Comment: I recommend to edit the question and additionally show the python version, which uses the same string inside the `()` and works. I have doubts. Maybe the string handling of python changes the string before SQLite ever sees it.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what Python (2.7) does. My question is for the CLI though. I realized my mistake with the quotes and tried removing them, as well as quoting each individual column name 'c1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows console appears to have a limit of 4096 bytes for entered lines.

Executing that string through any other mechanism (e.g., `.read` from a file) works fine.

Comment: Thanks! This issue affects the linux console as well.

`.read command.txt` works as expected